# How to shape input array appropriately for ML

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I apologize in advance if this question seems silly but I am trying to understand a [machinelearningmastery blog](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/) about LSTM type ML algorithms, more specifically on how the input data gets reshaped. And I dont have a ton of wisdom here on the subject or a CS degree for that matter

About half way into the blog about `LSTM CNN` section, Jason talks about:

> The first step is to split the input sequences into subsequences that
>   can be processed by the CNN model. For example, we can first split our
>   univariate time series data into input/output samples with four steps
>   as input and one as output. Each sample can then be split into two
>   sub-samples, each with two time steps. The CNN can interpret each
>   subsequence of two time steps and provide a time series of
>   interpretations of the subsequences to the LSTM model to process as
>   input.
>
> We can parameterize this and define the number of subsequences as
>   n_seq and the number of time steps per subsequence as n_steps. The
>   input data can then be reshaped to have the required structure:

`[samples, subsequences, timesteps, features]`

My question is this a requirement for the data to be only shaped into `4 steps`? Or can it be larger? This code below will attempt to print the array, I am using my own data sample [here](https://github.com/bbartling/Data/blob/master/trainData.csv) on my git account.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# univariate data preparation
from numpy import array



df = pd.read_csv("trainData.csv")
df = df[['kW']].shift(-1)
df = df.dropna()
raw_seq = df.values.tolist()


# split a univariate sequence into samples
def split_sequence(sequence, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if end_ix > len(sequence)-1:
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequence[i:end_ix], sequence[end_ix]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)

# define input sequence
#raw_seq = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
# choose a number of time steps
n_steps = 4
# split into samples
X, y = split_sequence(raw_seq, n_steps)
# reshape from [samples, timesteps] into [samples, subsequences, timesteps, features]
n_features = 1
n_seq = 2
n_steps = 2
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], n_seq, n_steps, n_features))
# summarize the data
for i in range(len(X)):
    print(X[i], y[i])
```

The code above works but when I change `n_steps = 7` (from 4) I get this shape error.

```
  File "convArray.py", line 39, in <module>
    X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], n_seq, n_steps, n_features))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2499 into shape (357,2,2,1)
```

The reason I want to try and use 7 time steps is the data that I am experimenting with is electrical demand units for a building per day, and 7 days in a week would be an ideal experimental time step!

Any tips greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mentioned in the error in this case. The problem is that you are trying to reshape the array to a specific shape but it is not possible. The array **X** has 2499 elements and 2499 cannot be reshaped to a (357,2,2,1) shape. The product of the numbers in the shape is the number of elements overall. A (357,2,2,1) has 357*2*2*1=1428 elements.
So your code returned an array with 1428 elements overall when `n_steps = 2`.
I think in your case, it is dependent on `raw_seq` because its length decides the number of times the for loop inside `split_sequence()` will run and the arrays it returns.`raw_seq` depends on the data, so for this dataset, `n_steps` might be limited.
I'm not 100% sure about it though.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I think I understand a little more

Comment: When `n_steps` is set to 4, it will return.. `(360, 2, 2, 1)`.  So the product would be 1440 elements.

Comment: @HenryHub And what's ```X.shape[0]```? Should change as well